# Matplotlib Live Plot in PyQt4 GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, pyqt4, live

I am writing a GUI using PyQt4, and am trying to implement a live updating pyplot chart using the matplotlib animate module.

The attached code works exactly as I am intending if an error conveniently occurs just before plt.show() is called in the main method (I have caused a div0 error here for demonstration).

If plt.show() is called however, 2 other windows are opened alongside the embedded graph (see screenshots). If any of these extra windows are closed, the embedded graph crashes. If plt.show() is removed from the code entirely, the chart live chart never works at all.

I am at a bit of a loss as to what is going on there. This behaviour is unexpected and quite confusing. It would be fantastic if anyone has any suggestions for how I might get everything working properly.

```
import sys
import json
import time
import math
import dateutil
import requests
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
style.use('ggplot')

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.time = []
    self.recorded_temp = []
    self.recorded_setpoint = []
    self.runtime = 0
    self.element_status = ""
    self.temp = 0
    self.setpoint = 0
    self.setWindowTitle("Distillation Control Panel")
    #self.setGeometry(100, 100, 500, 100)
    self.stacked_layout = QtGui.QStackedLayout()

    self.connect_page = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.home_page = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.home_UI()
    self.connect_UI()
    self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.connect_page)
    self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.home_page)
    self.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)

    self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_gui)
    self.show()

def main(self):
    self.timer.start(1000)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, interval=1000)
    1 / 0 # Code works if an error occurs here
    plt.show()

def home_UI(self):
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    runtime_indicator_label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.runtime = QtGui.QLabel()
    runtime_indicator_label.setText("Runtime: ")
    element_status_indicator = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.element_status = QtGui.QLabel()
    element_status_indicator.setText("Element Status: ")
    temp_indicator_label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.temp = QtGui.QLabel()
    temp_indicator_label.setText("Temperature: ")
    setpoint_label = QtGui.QLabel()
    self.setpoint = QtGui.QLabel()
    setpoint_label.setText("Setpoint: ")

    up_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Increase", self)
    up_btn.resize(up_btn.minimumSizeHint())
    down_btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Decrease", self)
    down_btn.resize(down_btn.minimumSizeHint())

    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

    grid.addWidget(runtime_indicator_label, 0, 0, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.runtime, 0, 1, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(element_status_indicator, 0, 2, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.element_status, 0, 3, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(temp_indicator_label, 0, 4, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.temp, 0, 5, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(setpoint_label, 0, 6, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.setpoint, 0, 7, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(up_btn, 0, 8, 1, 1)
    grid.addWidget(down_btn, 1, 8, 1, 1)
    grid.addWidget(self.canvas, 3, 0, 1, 9)
    grid.addWidget(self.toolbar, 4, 0, 1, 9)
    self.home_page.setLayout(grid)

def connect_UI(self):
    '''
    User interface for connecting to distillation controller server. Enter local IP address for ESP8266 
    assigned by router
    '''
    grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    addr = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    addr.setPlaceholderText("Enter IP address for distiller server")
    grid.addWidget(addr, 1, 1)

    btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Connect!", self)
    btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.connect(addr.text()))
    btn.setFocus()
    grid.addWidget(btn, 1, 2)

    self.connect_page.setLayout(grid)

def connect(self, addr):
    '''
    Check connection with controller server and verify address
    '''
    full_address = 'http://' + addr + "/connect"
    try:
        data = requests.get(str(full_address), timeout=1.0)
        if data.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'test', "Connected!", QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
            self.address = addr
            self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)
        else:
            # Add handling if non-200 http code returned
            pass

    except Exception:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'test', "Device not found at {}. Please enter a valid address".format(addr), QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.connect_UI()

    self.main()

def update_gui(self):
    full_address = 'http://' + self.address + "/request_data"
    data = json.loads(requests.get(full_address).text)
    runtime = convertMillis(data["Runtime"])
    temp = data['Temp']
    setpoint = data["Setpoint"]
    self.runtime.setText(runtime)
    self.element_status.setText(data["Element status"])
    self.temp.setText(str(temp))
    self.setpoint.setText(str(setpoint))

    self.time.append(dateutil.parser.parse(runtime))
    self.recorded_temp.append(temp)
    self.recorded_setpoint.append(setpoint)

def animate(self, i):
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(self.time, self.recorded_temp)
    plt.plot(self.time, self.recorded_setpoint)
    plt.xlabel("Running Time", fontsize=6)
    plt.ylabel("Temperature (°C)", fontsize=6)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=6, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=6)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.draw()

def convertMillis(millis):
    seconds = math.floor((millis/1000)%60)
    minutes = math.floor((millis/(1000*60))%60)
    hours = math.floor((millis/(1000*60*60))%24)
    return "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[I am unable to post screenshots, so here is a link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqAys.png)

Comment: what happens if you use plt.draw() instead of plt.show()? I believe plt.show() is starting it's own gui-mainloop that will interfere with your app.

Comment: If the code is allowed to run, plt.show() results in the screenshot above, and plt.draw() results in the plot never initialising.

Surprisingly, including the error just before the show/draw command does not behave the same as simply removing the plot/draw command entirely. With the error in place, the GUI app runs and updates correctly. With no error and the plot/draw removed, the graph does not run.

Comment: hm, I'm on qt5, so I can't directly run the code. I have had good experiences with pyqtgraph for integration with qt. I would probably try with a simpler codebase to try to hammer out where it goes wrong. Looking through the code once more I noticed that you are not keeping a reference to the animation, i.e it's ani =, I think I have read that one needs to  keep a persistant reference to animations, i.e. self.ani =. Doubt that this will affect your issue though.

Comment: Hey ahed87, just thought I would update you since I solved the problem. The solution was to use the draw method of the FigureCanvasQTAgg class, rather than the show method of the matplotlib.pyplot class. It was also necessary to maintain a persistent reference to ani so that it doesn't garbled up by the garbage collector. 

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: makes sense, glad that it worked out for you.